# How can i duplicate an array elements

Tags: matlab

i have an array in matlab software like this:

```
X=[x1,x2,x3];
```

And, I want to change this array to be like this:

```
X=[x1,x1,x2,x2,x3,x3];
```

Is there any command for doing this work in the simplest way ?

Comment: You have to be more precise. Is the size of the initial array fixed ? Do you want to copy each element just once or multiple times ?

Answer (score 0):

Use reshape and repmat like this

```
a=[1 2 3];reshape(repmat(a, 2, 1), 1, [])
```

repmat creates the amount of entries and reshape orders it as you asked.

Comment: Thanks a lot. it works...